# Reason not to delete legacy Columns from a table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, indexing, alter-table

My boss is convinced that you should never delete columns from a table in production (something about it could mess up index's).  Over the years this 'practice' has resulted in many of our tables becoming bloated with hundreds of unused, legacy columns.

Aside from having to refactor our (generated) datalayer, are there any solid reasons not to remove a unused column from a table?  Is my boss correct that it could break and index or have other side effects?

Comment: So just rebuild the indexes. Your indexes should be modified periodically as part of regular maintenance. Where did your boss hear this from?

Comment: who knows... He states that it has something to do with index's being referenced by their numeric column order or something.  I never really understood what he was trying to say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I started thinking about it and I came up with an issue not mentioned above.  Deleting Columns could potentially break views, functions and stored procedures if the columns are directly referenced by the queries.  In a well maintained/optimized system this would likely not be an issue (if it is truly not being used then it shouldn't be referenced anywhere).

Answer (score 2):

I've never encountered anything like that when dropping columns. You do have to clean up indexes as I don't believe you can drop a column that is currently used by an index. But you should be doing that anyways because leaving an unused column in an index won't help performance; it's more likely to hurt performance because the columns in the index won't match the columns needed.

Additionally, by keeping columns that aren't used, access will be slower because of the additional space needed for the unnecessary columns (which increases row size which means slower reads and fewer rows on a single data page).

Comment: I would like to hear your thoughts on the point I just posted (as an answer)

Comment: That shouldn't be an issue anyways. If a column is no longer needed, it shouldn't be used any longer. That means it shouldn't be referenced by views, functions, or stored proc's. If it is referenced by any of those, it is used AND the data contained in that column needs to be maintained otherwise your system will behave erratically.

Answer (score 1):

The only side effect I see is increased performance by reducing table's size and better indexes that don't use empty columns (if they were). You can't delete a column that is being used by an index, so you will have to recreate the indexes anyway. Go ahead and clean up your tables in a test environment first, make enough tests to be sure there are no side effects (it won't), then apply your changes in production. Also, let go your data/business modeler.